# Console output spits out Chinese(?) characters

Tags: windows, encoding, console

This is a real shot in the dark, however maybe someone had a similar issue. Some console apps are being invoked by either SQL Server 2008, or Autosys (job schedule) under Windows Server  2008; output results of execution are being saved into .txt files. Every so often, with no definite pattern as far as I can tell saved output is displayed as a series of what I presume are Chinese characters. Have anyone encountered phenomenon above?

Comment: I would be a little concerned! :/

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you discover chinese characters in output unexpectedly, it's because someone passed a 7-bit or 8-bit character array to an API which expected an array of unicode characters.  The system interprets the 8-bit characters as 16 bit unicode characters and they end up being interpreted as unicode characters.  At some point later the unicode characters are converted back to 8-bit characters, probably just before they're saved to the text file.

Note: This is an oversimplification but it should be enough to help you figure it out.